# Google Analytics incorrectly showing data from two sites

Tags: google, google-analytics, tracking, code

I have two websites that I've split up into two properties in Google Analytics with separate tracking codes. But for some reason when I view the raw data for Site A, it's showing me data from both.

I checked that the two properties have a different tracking code, and looked at the page source for site B, which only shows the correct, different tracking done (ending in -4 instead of -1). So why is the data from site A showing data from site B as well?

Comment: Are you sure the different tracking code you're seeing on site B is the only tracking code on that site at all? Are you using GTM at all with tracking there?

Comment: I'm using Exactmetrics plugin on Site A. I also had exactmetrics installed on Site B but recently deleted it. I remember I checked the plugin on both sites and it showed the correct tracking code. However, the reports on both sites showed me the data from both sides..so maybe it's this plugin that's causing the issue. Good catch

Answer (score 1):

This seems surprising to me. Though I am working with Analytics and have more than 100 properties registered under me, I did not face such problem.

I am pretty much sure that the tracking code of 'Site B' must be somewhere on some of the pages of 'Site A'. If you can just share the links of both sites, I can help you identify the issue.

Comment: Sure, the two sites are witcherhour.com and dragoninquisition.com. Thank you!

Comment: Yes... As you mentioned, you were using ExactMetrix and Yoast SEO simultaneously or one after another... Probably that thing caused this issue. On the page, it's definitely showing a single tracking code. On Homepage atleast. We need to figure out for every page individually